# Dot notation returns no results

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to use dot notation to find the list of Webs elements in this XML:

```
<Databases>
    <Database SiteCount="2" Name="MyDB" DataSource="BLAHDEV">
        <Site Id="72affdff-b0a9-404e-a000-08cfc1c2828a" OwnerLogin="Blah\Blah" InSiteMap="True">
            <Webs Count="1">
                <Web Id="5fb7df63-0ab3-4cb2-88de-1a94ceda0fbf" Url="/people/me/blah" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" TemplateId="21" />
            </Webs>
        </Site>
        <Site Id="9ae7dd88-cdd9-4d22-b6af-2185ddb22994" OwnerLogin="Blah\Blah" InSiteMap="True">
            <Webs Count="1">
                <Web Id="45d2d002-4e7d-4f22-9cd2-c93fdd49daab" Url="/people/me/blah2" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" TemplateId="21" />
            </Webs>
        </Site>
    </Database>
</Databases>
```

I then load it in powershell:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content MyXMLFile.xml
```

Querying using the dot notation works up until the Site element:

```
PS> $xml
Databases
---------
Databases

PS> $xml.Databases
Database
--------
Database

PS> $xml.Databases.Database
SiteCount             Name              DataSource      Site
---------             ----              ----------      ----
2                     MyDB              BLAHDEV         {Site, Site}

PS> $xml.Databases.Database.Site
Id                            OwnerLogin        InSiteMap                 Webs
--                            ----------        ---------                 ----
72affdff-b0a9-404e-a000-08... Blah\Blah         True                      Webs
9ae7dd88-cdd9-4d22-b6af-21... Blah\Blah         True                      Webs
```

However when I try to get the Webs elements, no results are returned:

```
PS> $xml.Databases.Database.Site.Webs
PS>
```

Is there a reason I can't find the Webs elements? Is it because there are multiple Site elements or some other reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$xml.Databases.Database.Site` is a Collection, you'll need to pipeline it:

```
$xml.Databases.Database.Site | Select -Expand Webs
```

Or use xpath (edit: SelectNodes is for each element, not the collection)

```
...Site | ForEach { $_.SelectNodes('Webs') } #or something similar
```

Or loop it

```
...Site | ForEach { $_.Webs }
```

Comment: Thanks, the first and last suggestion work. The second suggestion returns "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'SelectNodes'."

Comment: Oh that's right, it's a collection so the SelectNodes method would have to be in a ForEach, or computed property

Comment: Also remember you'll have to do the same thing if you add another `Database` node.